# I can't serialize form from the object

Tags: jquery, html, object, serialization

I use [scroll-pagination](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/) as a plugin in my page, And I use form to pass value to url i'm fetching the result.

After loaded new form will dynamically add to my page,and I want to serialize the new form to repete the progress with new page problem is, My code keep serialize the first form not the new one.

This is my Jquery

```
$(function(){
var datastring=$(".passform").last().serialize();
$('#update').scrollPagination({
    'contentPage': 'post_update.php', 
    'contentData': {
        data : datastring
        },
    'scrollTarget': $(window), 
    'heightOffset': 10, 
    'beforeLoad': function(){ 
        $('#loading').fadeIn(); 
    },
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ 
         $('#loading').fadeOut();
         var i = 0;
         $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
                 datastring=$(".passform",elementsLoaded).serialize();  //Here's the Problem:S
    }
});

$.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
        delay += 100;
    });};});
```

This is my first form in main code

```
<form id="passform" class="passform" name="passform">
        <input name="totalpage" type="hidden" value="<? echo($totalpage);?>" />
        <input name="nowpage" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input name="u_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo($u_id);?>" />
        </form>
```

This is the new form that Dynamically add

```
 <form class="passform" id="passform" name="passform">
        <input name="totalpage" type="hidden" value="<? echo($totalpage);?>" />
        <input name="nowpage" type="hidden" value="<? echo($nowpage);?>" />
        <input name="u_id" type="hidden" value="<? echo($u_id);?>" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

change first datastring:

```
var datastring=$(".passform").first().serialize();
```

and this datastring in `afterload`:

```
datastring=$(document).find(".passform").last().serialize();
```

### note:

Using same id for multiple elems is not valid. When this happens `then only first of its type will get selected.`

Comment: all loading in same form `.passform` or this is a new form with same class name `.passform`?

Comment: There's a new form with same class .passform  @Jai

Comment: Still not working:( Don't under stand why i can't re-define datastring in afterload. It seem to be the right way. (btw i update the question may be that'd help) @Jai

Comment: `$(document).find(".passform").last().serialize();` plz try once this.

Comment: and plz remove the `id` attr from both `forms`.

Comment: Yeah! Now i can re-define it. But code still send the old datastring,Dnt know why. But i think it's not hard to fix. Thank you for all of your answer @Jai